# My mom was homeless for 20 years; now has no legal identity

Tags: utah, identification, identity-theft

This is a real-world scenario but based on the theoretical question posted here: [What documents and testimony establish identity and what happens if they're lost?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30570/what-documents-and-testimony-establish-identity-and-what-happens-if-theyre-lost#new-answer?newreg=76dbc338ca24455280b86faecb839ebc)

---

My mother has a real problem in this regard, hoping you can help me identify how to navigate forward? Without going into too many of the details of her past:

- she was born in the U.S. and has always been a U.S. Citizen and has always lived in the U.S.
- dad passed away a few years ago and mom moved in with me; prior, they were indigent and lived for free room/board as innkeepers (someone else owned the inn)
- during the 20 years that her and dad worked as innkeepers:

  - her driver's license expired and she saw no need to renew b/c she wasn't driving (she has her expired DL)
  - she lost her SS card
  - their tax paperwork was in a storage shed that was broken into and vandalized and she doesn't know what happened to the paperwork (dad took care of it; she cannot find any copies)
  - they did not maintain any bank accounts
  - they did not file taxes (not smart of course, but since they weren't making income they didn't feel the need)
- she is 64yo and is now trying to apply for SS benefits
- SSA has talked to her on the phone and sent her mail here to our home with her name and SSN; they have processed her claim for benefits with the exception of having an account to deposit her funds
- Banks won't open account for her without an ID
- State DLD (Utah) won't issue a state ID without proof of identity (i.e. SS card)
- SSA won't issue replacement SS card without state ID
- Other forms of ID acceptable to State DLD are things like passport (she's never had), prior year's taxes (they were lost in the vandalism). The DLD told us this morning that expired ID isn't acceptable

Seems like an impossible-circle to re-establish her identity! Meanwhile, is there another way to get her an account for her SSA distributions?

Is there a such a thing as a "re-establishing your identity expert" we could hire to help us? Or a specific process to appear in-person, say in front of a judge, and get some sort of evaluation and legal order requiring DLD to issue her a new state ID?

She's basically an undocumented citizen, but was never an immigrant, and modern society has evolved to a point where we just left her behind during the years that dad and her were indigent.

Aside from giving her free room and board myself, I don't know how to help her!

Comment: Look at https://www.utahlegalservices.org/ and ask them to help with dealing with the state to get IDs.

Comment: Her birth certificate and SS card, togeather with your birth certificate and valid ID with you verifing before a judge that she is your your mother should be sufficient for a judge to make a determination of her identity.

Comment: Thank you @BlueDogRanch for the reference! Will check them out.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Unfortunately, while mom has an SSN she has lost her SS card. Regardless, is this a standard service I can request at any courthouse? No one from the DLD to the SSA has even suggested this approach to me but I would gladly do it.

Comment: Also a minor update: we might be out of the woods. Today I spoke with the SSA and they seemed to finally realize the problem and are sending her a 1099; the DLD has told us they will accept a 1099. YAY! Fingers crossed. :)

Comment: No idea what a 1099 is, but I assume something to replace a lost card. As to whether this is a standard procedure or not is something that may be jurasdiction specific, but in the end where doubts exist, a confirmation from a Judge that someone is who they say they are is more likely to resolve  a catch22 situation.